# Samba 4.5.12 in Debian 9 keeps asking for authentication in Windows 7

Tags: debian, samba

I have spent at least 8 hours trying to share a user directory /home/ivan/Share, this was an easy task in Debian 8 Samba 4.2.14 but imposible in the related setup reglardless all the configurations are the same (Passwords, SMBPassword, smb.conf)

```
[Share]
path = /home/ivan/Share
valid users = ivan
read only = no
```

Comment: The problem is usually due to changes in Windows over time. Last time I did it, I needed a registry tweak. Cannot remember it, and Windows not my beach, do your Google search.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm gonna set a public directory for guest with force user as a workaround, I am the only one using this VM after all...